# creating a mapped drive from variables

Tags: powershell

I had all this working but must have changed something because it doesn't now! I want to pass in variables and then from them create a mapped drive.

```
$d = "O:";
$s = "\\Server\Folder";
$u = "/user:DOMAIN\UserId password";
net use $d $s $u;
```

When I run that now, powershell just hangs.  I don't get any errors or nothing it just "runs" but doesn't complete.  I have to hit the stop script button.  If I check `net use` there is no entry for it in there.

if I manually type `net use O: \\Server\Folder /user:DOMAIN\UserId password` then it works and creates the mapped drive.

I have tried escaping the backslash as per below:

```
$d = "O:";$s = "\\\\Server\Folder";$u = "/user:DOMAIN\\UserId password";
```

also building the string like (with and without the escaped backslashes.):

```
$n = $d+' '+$s+' '+$u;
net use n;
```

this method advises the network cannot be found, again, with and without the escaped backslashes. How ever If I `echo $n` and paste the code it creates the drive so I am totally at a loss!

Answer (score 1):

Calling a CMD command within a PowerShell script you should use Invoke-Expression.

```
$d = "O:";
$s = "\\Server\Folder";
$u = "/user:DOMAIN\UserId password";

Invoke-Expression "C:\Windows\System32\net.exe use $d $s $u"
```